# why is my settings.json only showing the settings i have edited?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open my settings in my settings.json, the only code shown is the settings I have edited like a color scheme or font size. I want to show all my settings in the settings.json. Help?

Comment: There are user and workspace settings, see here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 0):

The reason VS Code only shows modified settings in your workspace is simply because those settings override your user/system-wide settings.

To view all your settings, just hit `CTRL + ,` and they'll be displayed. 
You can view the settings as JSON from there, and if you like have an exact duplicate of most of the data stored, just copy-paste those settings to your workspace.

Might I ask why you care so much about having all your settings in the workspace? Workspace settings are for **your** workspace, not necessarily for everyone else's.

Comment: 1) I forgot to mention that I am referring to the User Settings; 2) When I used the keyboard shortcut, I still ended up with the same settings in the json file; 3) I care about having all the settings in the JSON because–correct me if I wrong–I figure that having all settings is a way for me to access and edit the settings for the Code Runner extension's "code-runner.executorMap", which is my aim.

Comment: @michaelaplus Just change the directive in the UI. It'll show up in the JSON file as soon as you do.